# Adding satellite assemblies into XAP

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, xap, satellite

I have satellite assemblies pre-built and I want to add them into the silverlight xap file after the file has been built. I know if I do this manually all I need to do is add the files into the xap (it's a zip file) and update appmanifest.xaml.

Are there any tools out there (or msbuild task)  that I can call in the post build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dynamically load dll's at runtime. Have a look here: [Dynamic assembly loading](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-Dynamically-Loading-an-Assembly.aspx)

Have you considered using [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)? Here's a linke where they show how to download XAP's at runtime. [Silverlight TV 11: Dynamically Loading XAPs with MEF](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-11-Dynamically-Loading-XAPs-with-MEF/).

I hope this helps you.

BR,

TJ